# Calling jQuery function from different elements

Tags: jquery, xhtml, css-selectors

I'm pretty new to the jQuery world, so I'm hoping for some help.

I am creating a page that has a div that has a number of checkboxes inside of it.

Each of these checkboxes are contained in their own divs as well.

```
<div>
    <div>  
        <input type='checkbox' name='cb1' />
        <div id="info1">
            Hide
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <div>  
        <input type='checkbox' name='cb2' />
        <div id="info2">
            Hide
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div> ​
```

I need to write a jQuery function that be able to capture whenever either checkbox (cb1 or cb2) is clicked to hide/show it's corresponding 'info' div, (info1 or info2).

I'm going to have 100+ checkboxes so I'm hoping there is a way to do this without having to write 100+ functions for click().

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Mark - I just updated my answer. I didn't notice at first that you will have over 100 of those checkboxes. In that sort of situation, you should really use `.delegate()` so jQuery doesn't have to manage 100 separate yet identical event handlers. See my update. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var checkID = $(this).attr('name').substr(2);
    $("#info" + checkID).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

If a checkbox is initially unchecked, its info `div` should have `display: none;` declared on it.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is what I'm looking for!  Looks like I've got a lot to learn.  Any recommendations on where to learn more about selectors?

Comment: [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is probably the best place.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier with classes on your target items and to traverse the DOM instead of using specific IDs:

```
<input class='check' type='checkbox' name='cb1' />
<div id="info1">
Hide
</div>



$('.check').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This places [a `.change()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on all the checkboxes where the `name` [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `cb`.

When a change occurs, it traverses to [the `.next()` element](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling, and [calls `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which will show/hide based on whether the checkbox was checked or not.

**Example using your HTML:** http://jsfiddle.net/fWYtv/

```
$('input:checkbox[name^=cb]').change(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle( this.checked );
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since you stated that there will be over 100 of these, it would really be better to use  `.delegate()`, so you only have *one* handler instead of 100.

Take the main `<div>` that is a container for all of the, and give it an ID like `container`, so you end up with:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div>
        <input type='checkbox' name='cb1' />
        <div ...
```

Then [call `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on that, and set the `input` as the target of the event.

Like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fWYtv/1/

```
$('#container').delegate('input:checkbox[name^=cb]', 'change', function() {
    $(this).next().toggle( this.checked );
});
```

This will be a *much* more efficient way to go.

Comment: @Freek - Thanks. It's a handy feature of `.toggle()` being able to pass a boolean to ensure that the proper show/hide is done.

Comment: Indeed it is, and it actually gave me an idea for something that's been bothering me on one of my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
  if ( this.checked )
    $(this).next("div").show();
  else
    $(this).next("div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of checkboxes, consider using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on their common ancestor, as it is significantly faster than setting up hundreds of event handlers.